# material.svgAssetsCache injected in module of application - angular js

Tags: angularjs, svg, angular-material

I would like to know why the module `material.svgAssetsCache` is injected in code used on the Angular material website.

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
```

Here is an example of code on the AM website: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/button

I know the application uses svgs for icons, **but it still works without injecting** the  `material.svgAssetsCache` library.

Comment: It *doesn't* work without injecting it - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/QEAZNo

Comment: Thank you @camden_kid. I could not see the difference as I included the files directly in an img folder. As your code does not have an img folder it uses the file in the js file.

Comment: Should the below answer be accepted?

Answer (score 5):

According to a comment in the [Angular Material repository](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/docs/app/svg-assets-cache.js), that file should only be used in a `CDN Server` or an `Edge Server`:

```
/**
  * This 'svg-assets-cache.js' file should be loaded to a CDN or edge-server (currently S3).
  * The CDN url (for this file) is then used in `doc/app/js/codepen.js#L59` to identify an
  * external JS file that CodePen should load for 'launched' demos.
  */
```

So, at the end you are right. You don't need to include it if you are self hosting the material icons. It's only for CodePen.